# FTP 550 Access is denied

Tags: ftp

Client can connect and list directories in ftp server, but once starts to upload file, only 1mb is uploaded and then error 550 access is denied pops up. Client is using Filezilla. I tried from my office to coonect from inside and from 4G (outside) everything works. But client in other office tried 3 different PC's and the same error.
Here are logs from client:

```
2016-07-18 13:52:09 8396 1 Status: Connecting to x.x.x.75:21...
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: USER antzen
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 331 Password required
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: PASS *********
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 230 User logged in.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: SYST
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 215 Windows_NT
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: FEAT
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 211-Extended features supported:
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  LANG EN*
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  UTF8
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  PBSZ
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  PROT C;P;
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  CCC
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  HOST
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  SIZE
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  MDTM
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 211 END
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Status: Logged in
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: PWD
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: TYPE I
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 200 Type set to I.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,207).
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:10 8396 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/160718ant"...
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Command: CWD 160718ant
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 250 CWD command successful.
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Command: PWD
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 257 "/160718ant" is current directory.
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,208).
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Command: MDTM act348 cd-print2.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Response: 550 Access is denied. 
2016-07-18 13:52:17 8396 1 Status: Directory listing of "/160718ant" successful
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Status: Connecting to x.x.x.75:21...
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Command: USER antzen
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Response: 331 Password required
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Command: PASS *********
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Response: 230 User logged in.
2016-07-18 13:52:26 8396 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Status: Logged in
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Status: Starting upload of D:\x
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Command: CWD /160718ant
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 250 CWD command successful.
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Command: PWD
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 257 "/160718ant" is current directory.
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Command: TYPE I
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 200 Type set to I.
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,6,209).
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Command: STOR act348 cd-print5.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:27 8396 3 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Error: File transfer failed after transferring 1.310.720 bytes in 25 seconds
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Status: Disconnected from server
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Status: Connecting to x.x.x.75:21...
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Command: USER antzen
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Response: 331 Password required
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Command: PASS *********
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Response: 230 User logged in.
2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Status: Logged in
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Status: Starting upload of D:\x
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: CWD /160718ant
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 250 CWD command successful.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/160718ant"...
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: TYPE I
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 200 Type set to I.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,210).
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,211).
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: STOR act348 cd-print5.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Error: Could not write to transfer socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Error: File transfer failed after transferring 1.310.720 bytes in 1 second
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Status: Starting upload of D:\x
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/160718ant"...
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,212).
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:53 8396 3 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,213).
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Command: STOR act348 cd-print5.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Error: Could not write to transfer socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Error: File transfer failed after transferring 786.432 bytes in 1 second
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Status: Starting upload of D:\00 anthill18\10 aufträge\act348 cd-print5.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/160718ant"...
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,214).
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:55 8396 3 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,215).
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Command: STOR act348 cd-print5.rar
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Error: Could not write to transfer socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Error: File transfer failed after transferring 1.048.576 bytes in 1 second
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/160718ant"...
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Command: PASV
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,75,6,216).
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Command: LIST
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2016-07-18 13:52:57 8396 3 Status: Directory listing of "/160718ant" successful
2016-07-18 13:53:03 8396 1 Status: Disconnected from server
2016-07-18 13:53:57 8396 3 Status: Disconnected from server
```

EDIT: 
They are using the same account as we tested.

Comment: Are they using the same FTP account as you tested with?

Comment: Seeing this line `2016-07-18 13:52:52 8396 3 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity` make me think that the control connection times out after 20 seconds, and that makes FileZilla stop the upload on the Data Connection. You can try to ask the client to enable Keep-alive in FileZilla (Settings -> Connection -> FTP -> Send FTP keep-alive commands). This will make FileZilla send different commands on the control connection to keep it open.

Comment: You should only have censored the first two numbers of the IP. Knowing if both are in the same segment would narrow down the possibilities. Have you tried turning off the passive mode? It's possible that it's messing it up. If the server has a local and a public IP, try both, perhaps one will work for you. EDIT: Have you tried a file that is not potentially infected? A large JPEG would be ideal. Perhaps the antivirus is locking the file.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like quota related problem on that folder or user antzen. Did you try to upload something when loged as antzen and did you had same issue? You should test upload as admin to find out if you have user or folder quota problem. If quota's aren't problem, It could be firewall issue, so disable it and let your client test again and upload new log.